# Fullstack local setup doesn't load images

Tags: xm-cloud

After setting up the full stack locally, the rendering host is not able to load the newly added images. Network tab shows 404 for all those images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who is having this issue, please follow the steps below to resolve it. XM Cloud local setup uses the preview to fetch the content from the master database. There seems to be an issue with images as they are requested form the web database. The issue will be fixed in later revisions. If you are facing this now, fix it by pointing Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Web connection string to the master database locally. As web database is not used anymore for XM Cloud implementations, this shouldn't cause any harm. This connection string is defined in docker-compose.yml. You can change it in the file directly or override it in `docker-compose-overrid.yml`.

New value : `Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Web: Data Source=${SQL_SERVER};Initial Catalog=${SQL_DATABASE_PREFIX}.**Master**;User ID=${SQL_SA_LOGIN};Password=${SQL_SA_PASSWORD}`

`.Master` is the change.